# paramiko with Cisco ASA

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, asa

Does somebody try to use Paramiko to connect to Cisco ASA?

I use the following script:

```
import sys
import os
import paramiko


paramiko.util.log_to_file("ssh_conn.log")

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
print ('client created')
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ('key policy set')
ssh_client.connect(hostname='10.10.10.10', username='user', password='pass', port=22)
print ('client connected')
(stdin, stdout, stder) = ssh_client.exec_command('show version')
print ('command sent')
data = stdout.readlines()
print ('data read')
stdout.close()
ssh_client.close()
print ('session closed')
print (data)
```

It works well with Cisco IOS (routers), but hangs after "command sent" when I try to connect to ASA devices.

Paramiko log contains following messages:

```
DEB [20140718-18:12:52.534] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x23902b0
INF [20140718-18:12:52.537] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client Cisco-1.25)
DEB [20140718-18:12:52.923] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20140718-18:12:52.923] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-cbc, remote=aes128-cbc
DEB [20140718-18:12:52.924] thr=1   paramiko.transport: using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-cbc, remote aes128-cbc; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.040] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.041] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for 10.10.10.10: b'10d3ea97246086679196bda085796063'
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.066] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20140718-18:12:53.084] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.084] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.089] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet out: 4096 bytes
INF [20140718-18:12:53.089] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEB [20140718-18:12:53.094] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
```

I see active SSH session on the device, but my script hangs after output "command sent"

Comment: did you try running the ssh commands by hand? Is it possible it doesn't return any data on stdout (but on stderr instead)? In that case the stdout.readlines() might be just waiting for anything to read...

Comment: Yes, I tried to run command through SSH client and there was some output.

Comment: @adamski wrote: Did you find any answer to your problem? I got exactly the same actually... sending the command to asa never return... seems that SSH does not give the return char to validate the command... it is working well on switch and router by the way...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the process that I use to connect to a Cisco ASA:

```
import paramiko
ip = '1.1.1.16'
username = 'testuser'
password = 'password'
remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password,
                        look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output
remote_conn.send('enable\n')
remote_conn.send(password + '\n')
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output
```

I also have been working on a library (Netmiko) to simplify some of the Paramiko SSH handling. It is at https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko

Comment: Nice application Kirk.

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline character (`\n`) at the end of the command:

Before:

```
(stdin, stdout, stder) = ssh_client.exec_command('show version')
```

After:

```
(stdin, stdout, stder) = ssh_client.exec_command('show version\n')
```